# How do I get this game to end when the input is no without going back to the top?

Tags: python, python-3.x

How do I get this game to end when the input is no without going back to the top and looping through or getting an error code? Note I put "End" in so that it would not iterate again
import random

it's a simple guessing game that I want to start over if yes but end if no

```
def main():
    y_games = 2
    for y in range(y_games):
        play_guessingGame_()


def play_guessingGame_():
    guessesTaken = 0


    print('Hello Friend,\n')
    print('What is your name?\n')
    name = input()
    print(name + ' ,It is good to meet you!\n')
    print("Let's play a game!\n ")
    print('I am thinking of a number between 1 and 10. . . what is my number?\n')
    try:
        answer = random.randint(1,10)
        while guessesTaken < 5:
            print("Start guessing!\n")
            guess = input()
            guess = int(guess)

            guessesTaken = guessesTaken + 1

            if guess > answer:
                print('Too high! Try again!\n')
            elif guess < answer:
                print('Too low! Try again!\n')
            elif guess == answer:
                break

        while guess == answer:
            guessesTaken = str(guessesTaken)
            if guessesTaken == str(1):
                print('AND ON THE FIRST TRY!!! IMPRESSIVE!!!!')
                print('There is no beating you\n')
                break
            if guessesTaken > str(1):
                print('Good job! You guessed my number in ' + guessesTaken + ' guesses')
                print('There is no beating you\n')
                break

        if guess != answer:
            print("I'm sorry, you have run out of guess.\n")
            print('Better luck next time!\n')

    except ValueError:
        print('Please enter whole numbers only')


    print('\nDo you want to try again? ')
    response = input()
    if response == 'yes':
        print("Great! Let's do this!")

    if response == 'no':
        print('\nWell, all good things must come to end!')
        Exit

main()
```

Comment: You can use 'break' right?

Comment: I would move the greeting code, and the "try again" code into `main`. The `play_guessingGame_` function should just play the game, nothing more.

Comment: @pissall there is no loop to break out of. Easiest fix is to just import sys and call sys.exit(0)

Answer (score 0):

i added import random to your code and also changed Exit to exit() and there was no error and the game performed right, i hope i got your problem right..